# TV series about a detective on a near future police force

Tags: story-identification, tv

Don't remember a lot. Our hero was a detective on a city police force in the near future.

The only clear images I still have in my memory is him driving on a freeway and there were signs crossing over the road with advertising on them.

And he opened his phone like a small book and there was a video screen on one side and the push button numbers on the other. This stuck in my mind because I think this was years before cell phones! (Late 70s?)  I also seem to remember he had a partner and the series didn't last too long. Maybe a season or 2.

Comment: Did it have aliens in it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember.

Comment: Was his partner human or an android?

Comment: Again, I don't remember. About the only addition I can add is the signs over the road were like the big ones over the freeways now that inform you of traffic conditions and they were close together so you were always seeing some ads.